# Gsuite - Gmail Addon - How to test "Admin Install" domain wide authorization with service account before asking for final approval

Tags: google-workspace, gmail-addons

We have built a gmail addon and we want to test the "admin install" flow like a real user would do from the marketplace (or whatever is the closest way to test this).We want to test user experience so we can test the flow before we make our addon publicly available.

How do we do this? 
Is there any way to do the above? 
Is it that you just code assuming that all scopes needed by the addin would be granted without really having a way to test this before its published ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [publish the add-on to your own domain](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-gmail-addons#visibility) without review, and test it there.